# socket connection using retrofit in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I wish to create an open connection with my server to be sending a user's current location every 6 seconds. I was advised to use socket connection, please how can I create such connection with a retrofit if not what another way can I create a socket connection that sends users current location

Comment: is the connection one-sided or are you plannign to both send and receive data from server?

Comment: If you just send the location without any data send from the server maybe it is easier to use a POST (if you have the control of the backend).

Comment: no, this socket is dedicated to sending current location of a user ever 6 seconds

Answer (score 4):

Hello there you can try Firebase realtime database  for this

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database

From this you can create you observable sockets rather than creating from server side sockets

It can easily be implemented on any front end i.e Android, IOS and Web

Comment: Probably this is the best solution

Comment: I have an existing server that is requesting for the user's location.

Comment: You can use your server for everything except for the socket you can try it out

Comment: Firebase is sometimes slow, sometimes in realtime the onNewMessage() is invoked very late.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you're referring to is actually OkHttp's WebSocket

Refer here:

https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/WebSocket.html

You can implement it by hand or use some library - e.g. Tinder's Scarlet, which by design is inspired by retrofit:

https://github.com/Tinder/Scarlet

Comment: I would suggest you to set a RESTful HTTPS method on the server side and then access it from the Android device through Retrofit API.

Comment: Does this use Firebase real-time DB?